# C# check to see if property is accessed by the visual studio debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am writing a C# application. I have some objects with some lazy properties that actually do quite some work when you request their values.

I want to be able to check if they are called by the visual studio debugger when debugging and not execute them at all. For example when I click on an object with these properties then it shouldn't load them at all.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use Breakpoints to see if the debugger call them and #DEBUG in release mode to not load them at all.

Comment: While I'm not entirely sure what you want isn't (easily) doable I'm pretty sure it's not useful even if you could do it, you should rather make your life easier and put the code inside a function, not a property. Side effects in getters/setters aren't nice.

Comment: @rtur while true - properties that cache value (so perform heavy work once and then behave like normal properties) are quite common practice.

Comment: I'm racking my brain, but can't remember the exact name.  A later feature was added to .NET that prevents evaluating a watch when a property executes dangerous code.  The watch expression fails fast instead of executing that code.  Useful for thread synchronization primitives for example.  I can't find it back, it is obscure, hopefully this jiggers somebody else's memory.

Comment: @HansPassant You may be thinking of `nse`? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/06/26/7-lesser-known-hacks-for-debugging-in-visual-studio/

Comment: @mjwills: Holy cow, who thought of this? Really hard to remember

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [`DebuggerBrowsableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsableattribute.aspx):

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
```

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsablestate.aspx) state:

> Never -> Never show the element.

https://lostechies.com/jamesgregory/2009/08/18/debugger-property-evaluation-side-effects/ also briefly discusses the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the [excellent suggestion of @mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47247785/480982), if you don't have the source code or don't want to modify it at this point in time, turn the feature of in VS:

[image: VS Option dialog]